# What's the name of the idiom for #defining a symbol to nothing?

Tags: c++

If I see the line of code

```
#define IO_API __declspec(dllexport)
```

I would tell my colleagues "IO_API is defined to __declspec(dllexport)".

However, if I see the line of code

```
#define IO_API
```

I'm not sure what I would tell my colleagues briefly and unambiguously: any description tends to wander on a little. Is there a common descriptor?

Edit: I'm not looking for use cases here, merely a name for the idiom.

Comment: What's wrong with "IO_API is defined to nothing"?

Comment: I would probably say "I hash-def'd it to null", but there is I suppose the chance of confusion with `#define IO_API NULL`.

Comment: I'd say, `IO_API` is an empty token sequence. Because that's what the preprocessor does, token substitution.

Comment: The name of the idiom is "Usage of empty macro tags" (more rarely used, but also very applicable _"ifdef Hell"_).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Around here we just say

> The macro `IO_API` expands to nothing.

or

> The macro `IO_API` is empty.

It's really quite subjective but I think the former leads to the least amount of confusion.

Comment: I believe _"ifdef Hell"_ describes the "idiom" best (header guards excluded).

Comment: For further reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace